# Javascript navigation button, data-visible class problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

guys! I have some problems with my script. It's with my navigation button which if you press the tab should be coming up. I don't get any error codes. Could I get some help? It does give me value back in the console "true" or "false". I think the problem is not with the javascript more like with CSS or HTML. Thank you in advance!

```js
const primaryNav = document.querySelector(".nav-items");
 const navToggle = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-toggle");

 navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
     const visibility = primaryNav.getAttribute("data-visible");
     
     if(visibility === "false"){
         primaryNav.setAttribute("data-visible", true);
         navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
     } else if (visibility === "true"){
        primaryNav.setAttribute("data-visible", false);
        navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded" , false);
     }
 });
```

```css
html,body{
    margin: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url(../assets/Coding2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*-------Global Classes ------*/

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}


/* -------navbar-------*/

.nav{
    padding: 0 2rem;
    height: 0rem;
    min-height: 15vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav .nav-brand a{
    font-size:2rem;
    padding:1rem 1.5rem;
    
    position:relative;
    top: 15%;
    font-family: Arial, "Time New Roman";
    color: white;
}
.nav .nav-items{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}

.nav .nav-menu{
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}
.nav .nav-items .nav-link{
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: Arial, "Time New Roman";
    color: white;
    
}
.nav .social{
    padding:1.4rem 0;
}
.nav .nav-items a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, "Time New Roman";


}
.mobile-nav-toggle{
    display: none;
}
.nav .nav-items a > [aria-hidden="true"]{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-inline-end: 0.75rem;
}

@media (max-width: 35em){
    .nav .nav-brand a{
        right: 30%;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .nav .nav-items{
        --gap: 2em;

        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        inset: 0 0 0 30%;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: min(20vh, 10rem) 2em;
        background: hsl(0 0% 100% / 0.1);
        backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
        transform: translateX(100%);

    }
    .nav .nav-times[data-visible="true"]{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   
    
    .mobile-nav-toggle{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: url(../assets/icon-hamburger.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 2rem;
        aspect-ratio: 1;
        top: 2rem;
        right: 2rem;
        font-size: 0;
    }
}
/* ---X---navbar---X---*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Computer Science Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="./js/main.js" defer></script>
   <button class="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls ="nav-items" aria-expanded ="false"><span class="sr-only">Menu</span></button>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="nav-menu flex-row">
            <div class="nav-brand">
                <a href="#" class="text-gray">CBlogging</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul id = "nav-items" data-visible = "false" class="nav-items flex">
                    <li class ="nav-link">
                        <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">00</span>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-link">
                      <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">01</span>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-link">
                        <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">02</span>Article</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-link">
                        <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">03</span>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!---
            <div class="social text-gray">
                <a href="#">F</a>
                <a href="#">I</a>
                <a href="#">T</a>
                <a href="#">Y</a>
            </div>
            -->
        </div>


    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be faster if you give us codesandbox

Comment: I completely don't understand your query, Because your code isn't working in the snippet section too. can you refer some pages. from where we can see the example and let me help you.

Comment: This is the video I used some codes are different because I just wanted to put in the navigation tab only: https://youtu.be/HbBMp6yUXO0. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: Here is the codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-blackburn-e8s2c?file=/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

First step is change `background-color` like:

```css
body {
   background-color: #252525;
}
```

Now in button change `font-size` to example 17px:

```css
.mobile-nav-toggle {
   font-size: 17px;
}
```

Second and last step is change name of css atribute `.nav-times` to `.nav-items`:

```css
.nav .nav-items[data-visible='true'] {
   transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

That's it. Your welcome :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot even tho it was a little mistake. Thank you!